# Send email from Gmail alias using ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, actionmailer

I am developing an application in Rails and I managed to setup a mailer correctly. I can send emails with main_email@domain.com but want to send with alias_email@domain.com.

main_email@domain.com is setup at Gmail and alias_email@domain.com is, as the name suggests, an alias email to the main one. Is it possible to send email using ActionMailer with the Sender being the alias email?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no setup currently that can handle email aliases using gmail from Rails, you may want to use instead an email delivery services like Sendgrid or Mailchimp Transactional Email.